# Gradle task of Type: Test does not run

Tags: gradle

I have a task of Type: `Test`. When I run the task, it just says UP-TO-DATE and does not run the test that is, it does not execute the action in the doLast part of the task. Can you please help?

Thanks!

```
task runIntegrationTests(type: Test) {
    dependsOn compileIntegrationTestJava, processIntegrationTestResources, processTestResources

    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath

    doLast {
        logger.info("running Cuke tests")
        (new File('build/test-results')).mkdirs()
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
            args = ['--format', 'pretty',
                    '--format', 'html:build/test-results/cucumber-html',
                    '--format', 'json:build/test-results/cucumber.json',
                    '--tags',   '~@wip',
                    '--format', 'junit:build/test-results/cuke-junit-results.xml',
                    '--glue', 'src/integration/groovy', 'src/integration/resources']
        }
    }
}

:cleanTest UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build UP-TO-DATE
:compileIntegrationTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileIntegrationTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processIntegrationTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:integrationTestClasses UP-TO-DATE
:runIntegrationTests UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Answer (score 1):

You must declare inputs and outputs for your task in order to make it run. If no inputs to the task has changed it does not run. Add e.g. sourceset to your inputs. Take a look at the gradle docs, https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks

E.g:

```
task transform {
    inputs.file srcFile
    outputs.dir destDir
    ...
}
```